# Any Akamai APIs available ffor controlling the traffic manager?

Tags: api, akamai

We need to remove data centers from Akamai's global traffic manager frequently.

Are there any apis to do that via code rather than logging into the Akamai site each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the liveness test objects

Comment: As far as I know there is one liveness test for all DCs. Modifying that will take all DCs offline.

Comment: You basically have two options. 1. If you are using TM for failover you have liveness test objects placed on each DC, if these files are removed or does not generate a 200 OK reponse code TM will stop sending traffic to that DC. 2. TM for performance & failover, then you have both liveness test objects and load feedback files which can be modified to stop sending traffic to that DC.

Comment: Are there any APIs to do that?
I am using option #2 - Need to read up on feedback files though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a bunch of API to manage your GTM profile in Akamai:

https://developer.akamai.com/api/luna/config-gtm/overview.html